# How can I make logistic model with this data?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, anova

http://www.statsci.org/data/oz/snails.txt

You can get data from here.

My data is 4*3*3*2 completely randomized design experiment data. I want to model the probability of survival in terms of the stimulus variables.

I tried ANOVA, but I'm not sure whether it's right or not. 
Because I want to model the "probability", should I use logistic model??
(I also tried logistic model. But the data shows the sum of 0(Survived) and 1(Deaths). Even though it is not 0 and 1, can I use logistic??)

I want to put "probability" as Y variable. 
So I used logit but it's not working.
The program says that y is Inf.

How can I use logit as Y variable in aov?

```
glm_a <- glm(Deaths ~ Exposure + Rel.Hum + Temp + Species, data = data,
         family = binomial)    

prob <- Deaths / 20
logitt <- log(prob / (1 - prob))
logmodel <- lm(logitt ~ data$Species + data$Exposure + data$Rel.Hum + data$Temp)
summary(logmodel)


A <- factor(data$Species, levels = c("A", "B"), labels = c(-1, 1))
glm_a <- glm(Y ~ data$Species * data$Exposure * data$Rel.Hum * data$Temp,
             data=data, family = binomial)
summary(glm_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

`help("glm")` should direct you to `help("family")`, which reveals the following

> For the binomial and quasibinomial families the response can be specified in one of three ways:
>
> 1. As a factor: ‘success’ is interpreted as the factor not having the first level (and hence usually of having the second level).
> 2. As a numerical vector with values between 0 and 1, interpreted as the proportion of successful cases (with the total number of cases given by the weights).
> 3. As a two-column integer matrix: the first column gives the number of successes and the second the number of failures.

So for the question "How can I make logistic model with this data?", we can go with route #3 quite easily:

```
data <- read.table("http://www.statsci.org/data/oz/snails.txt", header = TRUE)
glm_a <- glm(cbind(Deaths, N - Deaths) ~ Species * Exposure * Rel.Hum * Temp,
             data = data, family = binomial)
summary(glm_a)
# [output omitted]
```

As for the question "I tried ANOVA, but I'm not sure whether it's right or not. Because I want to model the "probability", should I use logistic model?", it's better to ask on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It is also possible to have `Deaths > 0` as a response. (Case #1). A model with that response and no interactions seems to have a smaller AIC.

Comment: @RuiBarradas For option #1, it would be more appropriate to reshape the data to have `nrow(data) * sum(N)` rows; so, for example, the first row would become 20 rows (with each row having a response observation of 0), the last row would become 20 rows with seven of them having a response observation of 1 and 13 of them having a response observation of 0, etc. I believe this is discussed in (for example) Chapter 2 of Extending the Linear Model with R by Julian Faraway